# TypeScript Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 15. When apply a web request and want to print response-object to the console or any of it's properties:

```
JSON.stringify(data.someProperty) or
JSON.stringify(data.?someProperty) or
JSON.stringify(data)
```

the JSON is printed and valid. But I also get an error:

> Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON
> data undefined

How to parse a object with indeterminate properties?

In my.Component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.dataService.getRequest(this.testVar).subscribe((data:any)=>{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data.someProperty));
    });
  }
```

In my dat.service.ts:

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  getRequest(test: any){
    return this.httpClient.get("https://someRequest/returnofjson");
  }
}
```

Here is an example output of the json:

```
{
  "lat": 23.82,
  "lng": -9.4,
  "time_ms": 0.5710124969482422,
  "utc_offset_sec": 0,
  "tz": "GMT",
  "tz_abbr": "GMT",
  "elev": 38,
  "contact": {
    "code": 3,
    "time": "2023-04-17T04:00"
  },
  "units": {
    "time": "iso8601",
   },
  "dates": {
    "time": [
      "2023-04-17T00:00",
      "2023-04-17T01:00"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: _it looks like a valid JSON_ Can you show an example?

Comment: what happens when you `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(data?.someProperty));` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon please see my edits. The printed json is correct I validated with https://jsonlint.com/.